# How to see the stored procedure transaction logs in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to check the failed calls of particular stored procedure along with input values used.

Is there anyway to get that transaction logs from SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Check [LINK](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3076/how-to-read-the-sql-server-database-transaction-log/) or [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190925.aspx)

Comment: Take a look at the SQL Server Profiler, read the docs and be careful, but you can easily watch for those errors in real-time against the server with the correct filters set.

Comment: Haven't tried this, but sounds like something you could do with extended events.